# How to get byobu help screen (shift-F1) to work under a fish login shell?

Tags: fish, byobu

I can get the Shift-F1 to show the help for a user that has fish as login shell.

I get a glimpse of an error message that gets quickly overwritten.

It says

```
fish: Variables may not be used as commands. Instead, define a function like 'function BYOBU_PAGER; sensible-pager $argv; end' or use the eval builtin instead, like 'eval $BYOBU_PAGER'. See the help section for the function command by typing 'help function'.
```

If I change the login shell back to `/bin/bash` with `chsh` then Shift-F1 will show the help page as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating a bit it seems that Shift-F1 is keybinding is defined in `/usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux`

```
bind-key -n S-F1 new-window -k -n help '$BYOBU_PAGER $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/doc/byobu/help.tmux.txt'
```

And that command fails because it's executed in the fish shell and fish shell doesn't allow a variable to be used as  a command.

Changing the binding to

```
bind-key -n S-F1 new-window -k -n help 'sh -c "$BYOBU_PAGER $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/doc/byobu/help.tmux.txt"'
```

will work since it will use `sh` to run the command.

Comment: I created a bug report in [byobu launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu/+bug/1392693) to address this issue